# VBA to create word document from excel: Word document not opening

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

So I modified the following code from an online tutorial and to start with it worked perfectly, but I could only get it to create documents if word was completely quit before running the code. However now the code seemingly runs without problem but only opens the word launchpage and won't open an actual document. I know this could just be a word issue rather than a coding issue but I really don't know what I'm doing so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also I work on Mac, don't know if that changes anything!

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateLetters()

Dim wdApp, wdDoc As Object
Dim LastRow, HouseRow, HouseCol, DaysPassed As Long
Dim FileName, TagName, TagValue As String

With ThisWorkbook

On Error Resume Next
Set wdApp = GetObject("Word.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
Err.Clear
Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wdApp.Visible = True
End If

On Error GoTo 0

LastRow = Range("B9999").End(xlUp).Row
    For HouseRow = 3 To LastRow
        DaysPassed = Range("K" & HouseRow).Value
        If DaysPassed < 1 Then
            Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(FileName:="/Users/username/Desktop/File/Document.docx", ReadOnly:=False)
            For HouseCol = 2 To 8
                TagName = Cells(2, HouseCol).Value
                TagValue = Cells(HouseRow, HouseCol).Value
                    If IsEmpty("HouseRow" & "HouseCol") = False Then
                        With wdDoc.Content.Find
                        .Text = TagName
                        .Replacement.Text = TagValue
                        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
                        End With
                    ElseIf IsEmpty("HouseRow" & "HouseCol") = True Then
                        With wdDoc.Content.Find
                        .Text = TagName
                        .Replacement.Text = Chr$(8)
                        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
                        End With
                    End If
            Next HouseCol
        wdDoc.SaveAs2 "/Users/username/Desktop/File/" & Range("A1").Value & "/Word/" & Range("B" & HouseRow).Value & "_" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy") & ".docx"
        wdDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:="/Users/username/Desktop/File/" & Range("A1").Value & "/PDF/" & Range("B" & HouseRow).Value & "_" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy") & ".pdf", ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF
        wdDoc.Close
        Range("K" & HouseRow).Value = Now
        Range("N" & HouseRow).Value = "1"
        End If
    Next HouseRow
    wdApp.Quit
    
End With
    
Set wdApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: You  turn the error reporting off with On Error Resume Next. turn it on again by on error GoTo 0  after Err.Clear , this should be your starting point. check if there is any error with your code

Comment: Try insert `On Error Goto 0` before `LastRow = Range("B9999").End(xlUp).Row`, `On Error Resume Next` might be hiding any other errors that occured after setting `wdApp`.

Comment: @RaymondWu So I've added the `On Error GoTo 0` line and now the error I'm receiving is a Run-time error 91: Object Variable or With Block Variable not set. with the following line highlighted: `Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(FileName:="/Users/username/Desktop/File/Document.docx", ReadOnly:=False)`

Comment: When the error occured, is the Word Application still visible? Did it show `wdApp` as Nothing in the local window? Is the file path given exist and is valid? @edgy444

Comment: @RaymondWu The Word Application opens to the launch page and is visible, I'm not sure what you mean by showing `wdApp` as Nothing in the local window but the file path should be valid as it was directly copied from the file itself. The error is now showing as Run-Time Error '424': Object Required (same line of code highlighted)

Comment: @RaymondWu I think I understand what you meant by "showing as nothing in the local window" - when I hover over `wdApp` in the editor then it says 'wdApp = Nothing' in a small box, the same happens with `wdDoc` too. Further to this the error is now showing 'Run-Time Error '91' Object Variable or With Block Variable not set' again.

Comment: "I work on Mac, don't know if that changes anything!" - There is a long-standing issue with this sort of automation on the mac.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt I feared that would be the case, I have been trying different variations on rotation and finally something worked, although I had tried the same thing with no success multiple times before, seems to be no sense to it at all :(

Comment: AFAIK Microsoft haven’t acknowledged the issue. I haven’t seen an explanation of the cause, but it is possibly due to Office running sandboxed.

Comment: @edgy444 try `GetObject(,"Word.Application")` with "Word.Application" as the 2nd argument instead of 1st.

Comment: If the above works but CreateObject can't hold the reference to the application then perhaps you can add an error handler to GetObject back...